# How can I call lanes with parameters from within my lane?

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I have a Fastfile,and  I want to all lanes with parameters from within my lane .How can do this? Just like this:

```
lane :my_lane do
     other_lane paramter1_name:"1" parameter2:"2"
end
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You should do it in this way:

```
lane :my_lane do
  other_lane(
    parameter1: '1', 
    parameter2: '2'
  )
end
```

Hope this helps!

So other lane should be

```
lane :other_lane do |values|
   parameter1  = values[:parameter1]
   parameter2  = values[:parameter2]
   puts parameter1
   puts parameter2
end
```

Comment: Lanes are like actions in this regard, so you have to supply parameters to them in the same way as well.

Answer (score 3):

this will also work

```
lane :other_lane do |values|
    parameterValue1 = values[:parameterKey1]  #read from arguments
    parameterValue2 = values[:parameterKey2]  #read from arguments

    #call other_lane with arguments
    other_lane parameterKey1:parameterValue1 parameterKey2:parameterValue2
end
```